# why I have HTTP 403 from repo spring?

Tags: java, spring, gitlab, jhipster

I have a jhipster project which deploy on heroku with gitlab since several months

Since yesterday, I can not deploy new version because I have this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
32 * What went wrong:
33 A problem occurred configuring root project 'yvidya'.
34 > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
35    > Could not resolve io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.10.RELEASE.
36      Required by:
37          project :
38       > Could not resolve io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.10.RELEASE.
39          > Could not get resource 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-    release/io/spring/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.10.RELEASE/propdeps-plugin-0.0.10.RELEASE.pom'.
40             > Could not GET 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/io/spring/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.10.RELEASE/propdeps-plugin-0.0.10.RELEASE.pom'. Received status code 403 from server:     Forbidden
```

Anyone know why this error? and how solve it?

Comment: issue is with http call..   try with https.   "http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/io/spring/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.10.RELEASE/propdeps-plugin-0.0.10.RELEASE.pom"

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Open your **`build.gradle`** file and replace the spring maven repository URL from **http** with **https**

Comment: I changed the url in the build.gradle file in buildscript -> repositories -> maven with the new https endpoint

Comment: I changed the url in the build.gradle file in buildscript -> repositories -> maven with the new https endpoint

Comment: I think the accepted answer should incorporate @Nayeem's comment below.

Comment: I don't even have a spring repository repo defined in my pom.xml, so it should have resolved to Maven Central.  In other words, there's no explicit repo URL to change from "http" to "https"

Answer (score 21):

The issue is related to the deprecated repository link. Please update `http` with `https` of Spring repo URL.

Comment: Yes, As per the post on Spring.io 
"In response to our nohttp announcement, Maven Central’s announcement, and JFrog’s announcement, beginning January 15 2020, Spring’s Maven Repository will no longer support HTTP. More concretely, http://repo.spring.io will not respond to requests."

https://spring.io/blog/2019/09/16/goodbye-http-repo-spring-use-https

Comment: I changed the url in the build.gradle file in buildscript -> repositories -> maven with the new https endpoint

Answer (score -1):

The `HTTP Response Code` you are getting is `403` which means `FORBIDDEN`. one of the main reasons to get such an error requesting general repositories, could be the restrictions that are applied for some countries due to some sort of sanctions. countries like North Korea, Syria, Iran and some other places.

If that's the case, i suggest using some kind of proxy that isn't located in those countries. and then try again. this time i think you would be able to fetch dependencies from `Spring` repositories.

Comment: In general a 403 status does not indicate that any sanctions have been imposed. The accepted answer above is the actual reason for the error here.

Comment: i said one of the main reasons could be the restrictions. Here in Iran developers face FORBIDDEN response code a lot when they try to fetch dependencies from several repositories. and that's mostly because of sanctions. I thought maybe this answer could be helpful for those developers developing at such circumstances.

Comment: Some non-sanctioned country developers should consider that restricted country firewalls might return 403, although I would think it could also be 503.

Comment: I miss you bro, good luck.